# Can there be a basis for a set that's not a subspace of $R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have $W$, which I've come to the conclusion is not a subspace of $ V$. Now the last question of my homework is that there are $4 W$'s which in a previous question had to be identified as being or not being subspaces of $V$'s. $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ were subspaces of $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$. However $W_4$ was not a subspace of $V_4$.

The question is to find a basis for $W_1$, $W_2$, $W_3$ and $W_4$... Now, since $W_4$ is not a subspace of $V_4$... Can there even be a basis for it in the first place?

Comment: The definition of a basis starts like this: "Given a vector space $W$, a basis of $W$ is...". You can certainly apply this when $W$ is a subspace of another vector space, because a subspace is a vector space in its own right. But no, if something is not a vector space, then a basis for that something is not defined.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you very much. This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no definition of basis for arbitrary subsets of a vector space.

Comment: Ok so W4 has no basis. Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you understand *why*? Its because its not a *vector space* if it were there certainly would have been one. Did you mean subspace or subset?

Comment: @Shamim Translating the question (because it's not originally in English) it goes something like this: For each of the vector subspaces in exercise 7, find a basis and provide its dimension.

There was a question about the basis of R2, R3, etc. and then a question about the basis of specific subspaces. I'm pretty sure it was not about subset.

I was almost certain there would be no basis for a set that's not a subspace of Rn, but I wanted confirmation and I wondered if I had to try and fail to prove it, or if I should just answer that there is no basis. I went with the latter and explained

Comment: well, the question is clear, for each of the subspaces, so you don't have to do it for the ones that aren't subspaces.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Yeah, that's what I figured. Thank you.

Comment: No problems, happy to help.